# How do I implement dynamic routing in python?

Tags: python, dynamic, routes, wsgi

I am attempting to have the url input be (some kind of url)/page/(whatever page number of the template we want). I am having trouble with this, and am not sure what the issue is. The first part of my code goes as follows:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from wsgiref.util import setup_testing_defaults
routing_table = {}

def route(url, func):
routing_table[url] = func

def find_path(url):
if url in routing_table:
    return routing_table[url]
else:
    return None

def app(environ, start_response):
setup_testing_defaults(environ)
handler = find_path(environ['PATH_INFO'])
if handler is None:
    status = '404 Not Found'
    body = "<html><body><h1>Page Not Found</h1></body></html>"
else:
    status = '200 OK'
    body = handler()
headers = [('Content-type', 'text/html: charset=utf-8')]
start_response(status, headers)
return [body.encode("utf-8")]

def run(ip, port):
myserver = make_server(ip, port, app)
print("Serving testings of wsgi at http://%s:%s" % (ip, port))
myserver.serve_forever()
```

The next part of the code is where I believe the main issue is occurring at page(page_id):

```
import test
import re

def index():
return "This is the main page"

def hello():
return "Hi, how are you?"

def page(page_id):
return "This is page number: %d" % page_id

if __name__ == '__main__':
test.route("/", index)
test.route("/Hello", hello)
test.route('/page/<page_id>', page)

test.run("127.0.0.1", 8000)
```

My thinking is that we need to import the template, and have the logic defined within the templates, themselves. However, when I attempt to do this, I am unable to "from python import Template" and utilize the template(myTemplates.tpl). I believe my syntax may be incorrect, but python.org has shown no suggestions, thus far.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this yourself? There are hundreds of Python micro-frameworks that take care of routing for you: Flask, webapp2, Bottle, etc.

Comment: @DanielRoseman maybe it's a learning excercise. I'd look at the code of those microframeworks for the answer

Comment: This is a project to create our own web framework. We're not looking for a blatant answer, but just a nudge in the right direction. I feel we are stuck on attempting to import the templates.

Comment: I feel like the answer is a one-line import statement, but could be wrong. I will dive into bottle.py code and see what they've done.

Comment: @kcmallard did you get a good approach at the end?

Answer (score 1):

In `find_path` you are simply comparing the given string to one of the URLs on the routing table

```
if url in routing_table:
```

So the only page you could actually reach for the `'/page/<page_id>'` route is the literal `'/page/<page_id>'`.

What you would need to do is parse the URL to see if it matches the format you are passing in, not compare the static string. Makes sense right?

In that case you might wanna look into regular expressions: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: I may be doing this very, very wrong....    def find_path(url):
 if url in routing_table & url == [0-9]:
  return routing_table[url + "<page_id>"]
 else:
  return None

Comment: `&` is a bitwise operator. What you are going to need is the functions defined in the [re](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) module. This article has an introduction to regex.